# Wordpress alterna Theme Fatal error memory size Limit

Tags: php, memory, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have tried for 2 days but still not get any solutions. I checked:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
```

In **wp-config.php:**

> **Fatal error:** Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in /home/mytheme/public_html/wp-content/themes/alterna1/inc/penguin/tools/less.php/Less.php on line 1027

The theme is *Themeforest alterna*. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a bad loop or some sort of other conflict? It doesn't sound like a memory problem. A bad loop or other programming error will cause an out of memory error.

Comment: @Rasclatt ..i uses theme from themeforest ..i getting error in less.php file

Comment: Also, may be a typo, but your `ini_set(‘memory_limit’,’128M’);` has apostrophes and not quotes. `‘` vs `'`

Comment: I didn't touch any code, i just added page and content...yes i moved it from localserver to live

Comment: I am not familiar with that that theme, but if it's that one page, you can go onto that page and remove elements until the error resolves, then you can kind of figure out where the issue is.

Comment: yup sorry it's typing mistake in question : i already checked with 
`ini_set('memory_limit','128M');` but not working

Comment: Also you can ask your host company to increase memory limit, and you can ask the theme devs what that is, since you have the right to support...

Comment: ok let's check, i removed all code from less.php and uploading

Comment: I usually take out like have the page of code and set it aside. If it doesn't load still keep removing more, but failing that, @dingo_d has the next step which is just to confirm with the developer(s) of the theme. They could probably tell you easily enough.

Comment: have you tried to set the memory limit through .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes still not getting solution...